# Which approach is better use of HttpClient in .NET Framework 4.7?

Tags: c#, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient, .net-4.7, sendasync

Which approach is the better use of `HttpClient` in .NET Framework 4.7?

In terms of socket exhaustion and thread safe? Both are reusing `HttpClient` instance, right?

I can't implement `IHttpClientFactory` right now. It is difficult to us to implement dependency injection

First code snippet:

```
class Program
{
    private static HttpClient httpClient;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("your base url");
        // add any default headers here also
        httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0); // 2 minute timeout

        MainAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        await new MyClass(httpClient).StartAsync();
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary;
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public MyClass(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        myDictionary = await UploadAsync("some file path");
    }

    public async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> UploadAsync(string filePath)
    {
        byte[] fileContents;

        using (FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            fileContents = new byte[stream.Length];
            await stream.ReadAsync(fileContents, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        }

        HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
        // your request stuff here

        HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, CancellationToken.None);

        // parse response and return the dictionary
    }
}
```

Second code snippet:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        await new MyClass().StartAsync();
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary;
    private static readonly HttpClient httpClient= = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("your base url"), Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0) };

    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        myDictionary = await UploadAsync("some file path");
    }

    public async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> UploadAsync(string filePath)
    {
        byte[] fileContents;

        using (FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            fileContents = new byte[stream.Length];
            await stream.ReadAsync(fileContents, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        }

        HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
        // your request stuff here

        HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, CancellationToken.None);

        // parse response and return the dictionary
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to resolve socket exhaustion problem.

Comment: I recommend reading [You're (probably still) using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/). Either of your options will solve your socket exhaustion problem, but long lived handlers won't respect DNS changes.

Comment: Look at also [You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

Comment: Hand the problem off; use Flurl.Http library for an easy life, and let it manage HttpClient

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama In both codes that I have shown using static httpclient like article says.But which one is better?First one second one?Sometimes I'm getting "Task is cancelled" .

Comment: Your `UploadAsync` fuction is completely broken, you aren't actually uploading the file at all. And you are missing `using` on the request and response.

Comment: @Charlieface There may be issues in UploadAsync, please look into httpclient part